# function uc_stock_adjust($sku, $newStock); not returning any value

Tags: nodes, hooks

Iam using uc_stock module functions of ubercart module in my function but not getting result as i want. here is my code:

```
function my_module_node_presave($node) {  
  if ($node->type == 'add_stock') {
    if (module_exists('uc_stock') && function_exists('uc_stock_adjust')) {
      $newStock = $node->field_stock_value['und'][0]['value'];
      drupal_set_message('new stock :' . $newStock);

      $sku = $node->field_sku['und'][0]['value'];
      drupal_set_message('sku :'. $sku);

      $key = $node->field_reference['und'][0]['nid'];
      drupal_set_message('key :'. $key);

      $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_sku');
      drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($items, true) . "</pre>"); 
      $sku = $items[0];
      drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($sku, true) . "</pre>");     

      $stock_adjust = uc_stock_adjust($sku, $newStock);
      drupal_set_message('stock_adjust :'.$stock_adjust);

      $stock_set = uc_stock_set($sku, $newStock);
      drupal_set_message('stock_set :'.$stock_set);
    }
  }
}
```

in my code

---

$stock_adjust = uc_stock_adjust($sku, $newStock);

$stock_set = uc_stock_set($sku, $newStock);

the above two functions were returning no value. now anyone can tell me whats the problem in my code

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call a function of a module in custom module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58244/how-to-call-a-function-of-a-module-in-custom-module)

Answer (score 0):

Function [uc_stock_adjust](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api/uc_stock_adjust) has no return value.

> Description: This function adjust a particular product SKU by a
>   certain value (a positive integer will add to stock, a negative
>   integer will remove from stock).
>
> Parameters:
>   $sku - The product SKU that will have its stock level adjusted
>   $qty - The quantity to add to the stock level
>
> Return value: **No return value.**

Comment: how can use uc_stock module with my custom module. I want to use the functioning of uc_stock module in my custom module. First, this is possible? if yes. how?